# Extension of Set where element is an Array of a specific type

Tags: swift, swift2

I would like to add an extension to the Set struct, but only if the element of Set is an Array of NSOperations. Is it possible?

I want to write something like this, but it's not a valid code:

```
extension Set where Element : Array<NSOperation> { }
```

because `type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'Array<NSOperation>`. So I wanted to create a protocol and extend Array of NSOperations with this protocol:

```
protocol ArrayOfOperations { }
extension Array : ArrayOfOperations where Element : NSOperation { }
```

It doesn't work either because `Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause`.

So I'm kinda lost here. Do you have some idea, how to solve this?

Comment: How would you construct a "Set of Array of NSOperations" (`Set<[NSOperation]>`)? `[NSOperation]` is not `Hashable`.

Comment: @MartinR import Foundation
let op = NSOperation()
var arr: Array<NSOperation> = []
arr.append(op)
let set = Set(arr)

Comment: @user3441734: That creates a set from the array and  gives you a "Set of NSOperation", not  "Set of Array of NSOperation" .

Comment: aha, sorry ... array is not Hashable, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot make `Array<NSOperation>` conform to `Hashable` you'll have to make a small wrapper-struct.

E.g.

```
struct NSOperationList {

    var operations = [NSOperation]()
}
```

and then build all functionality you need on top of `NSOperationList`.
So if you want to add support for `Set`:

```
extension NSOperationList: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int {
       return operations.reduce(0) { $0 ^ $1.hashValue }
    }
}

func == (a: NSOperationList, b: NSOperationList) -> Bool {
    return a.operations == b.operations
}
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand OP question. you are right!

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

let op = NSOperation()
var arr: Array<NSOperation> = []
arr.append(op)
let set = Set(arr)
```

i don't know what is your trouble, but above snippet compiles without any trouble

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand OP question ... my mistake. fluidsonic answer is correct